# Export results of the command tree in csv file with columns

Tags: linux, terminal

I need to save the results of our directory structure, only folders, from the linux server and export the results in a csv file with columns.

What I tried and works best is `tree -d /path/folder/ -L 3 > file.csv`
I tried to combine with `column` but my knowledge is ye.. limited.

Best would be if I can list the first level of a directory in column A, second level in column B and the last one in column C.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to only list files that are three levels deep:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 | sed 's:./::;s:/:,:g' > file.csv
```

But I generally don't see any goods from trying to translate a file structure to a csv file. That doesn't seem to be any useful.